# I can't change Temporary Directory in my Drupal 7 site

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm on the process of moving my Drupal 7 website from development to production. Now I can't change my site's temporary directory.

Every time I try to change the path it gives me an error that it can't execute `mkdir()` function.

I also tried to change it using `devel` module variable editor, it gave me a successful message but the value stayed the same. (The old value)

I also removed the variable from the `variable` table, and it stayed the same.

I really don't know what to do here!

Any ideas ?!!!

Comment: Make sure you have write access to the new temporary directory you are trying to point to.

Comment: Already did. I have also tried adding this inside `sites/default/files` folder and it hasn't worked either.

Comment: You have write access or the user Drupal is running as has write access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the obvious culprit would be permissions, there are other gotchas, such as trying to set it to /tmp and not tmp. /tmp is owned by your server OS. Use tmp without the leading slash for the Drupal directory inside your files folder.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, /tmp is not accessible by the web user (I'm using latest version of AlternC control panel http://alternc.org/ )

I just changed the path in drupal variable table :

```
mysql> update variable set value='s:28:"/var/www/alternc/u/user/temp";' where name='file_temporary_path';
```